# How to reorder rows in SfDataGrid in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I want to add reorder feature for rows in the SfDataGrid, I know how to add this feature with ReorderableListView for a listview but I want this feature for SfDataGrid, here is my code:

```
class CourseTable extends StatelessWidget {
  const CourseTable({
    super.key,
    required this.ref,
    required this.dataGridRows,
    required this.titles,
  });

  final WidgetRef ref;
  final List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows;
  final List<String> titles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: deviceSize(context).height * 0.05,
        horizontal: deviceSize(context).width * 0.05,
      ),
      child: SfDataGrid(
        columnResizeMode: ColumnResizeMode.onResizeEnd,
        allowColumnsResizing: true,
        defaultColumnWidth: 200,
        allowEditing: true,
        source: CoursesDataSource(
          context: context,
          ref: ref,
          dataGridRows: dataGridRows,
        ),
        columns: List.generate(
          titles.length,
          (index) {
            final title = titles[index];
            return GridColumn(
              columnName: title,
              label: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


  List<DataGridRow> filterByLevel(CourseLevel level) {
    final filteredCourses = courses.where((course) {
      return course.level == level;
    }).toList();

    filteredCourses
        .sort((course1, course2) => course1.rank!.compareTo(course2.rank!));

    return filteredCourses
        .map<DataGridRow>((course) => DataGridRow(cells: [
              const DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: '',
                value: 'Drag',
              ),
              DataGridCell<bool>(
                columnName: 'Is Public?',
                value: course.isPublic,
              ),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: 'Thumbnail',
                value: course.image,
              ),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: 'Title',
                value: course.name,
              ),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                columnName: 'Instructor',
                value: course.instructorId,
              ),
              const DataGridCell<Widget>(
                columnName: 'Action',
                value: Icon(Icons.edit),
              ),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: Try to add  `allowSorting: true,` and  `allowFiltering: true,`  inside SfDataGrid